# How to Create a list of value with data base store image in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, html, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a column of product_id in my form view and I show product image in the list of the value of "product_id" column my code is below but not working.

[image: [image]]

```
select '<img src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P5_PRODUCT_IMAGE',p.product_id)||'" />' detail_img,
 product_id from PRO_PRODUCT_INFO_MST p
```

and run time list of value look like this:
[image: [run time image]]

Comment: Popup LOVs don't (yet) have support for toggling the escaping of special characters. I'm working on a workaround for you, but it will depend on two variables: the Display As value and whether you want multiple columns or not. Your current Popup LOV has Display As set to Inline Popup and it's using only a single column. Will either of those change?